# SonarJS marks issues if FlowType type annotations from the standard library are present

Tags: sonarqube, sonarjs

SonarJS 4.0 ignored FlowType annotations, but with SonarJS 4.1 they are marked as reference error (Rule: javascript:S3827).

I just want to clearify if this is intended behaviour and what is the intended "workflow" regarding this.

if it is not a bug, do i need to add all those References to the globals, or what is the best practice to handle this behaviour?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: However, I stumbled upon https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1609 . I am not very familiar with react, can you confirm that it is possible to import `SyntheticInputEvent` , or perhaps they should be also added to the global scope?

Comment: actually there are multiple events "SyntheticEvent", "SyntheticInputEvent", "SyntheticMouseEvent", which are right now popping up -> but i am not sure if there are more, and well the work arround would be adding them to the global scope - but still a lot of effort to maintain such a list, if it extends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behavior, SonarJS version 4.1 now treats Flow Types as symbols, and core flow types are automatically resolved because they are available in the new `flow` environment. Types should be resolved automatically when they are correctly imported with `import type` syntax.

[An issue](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/issues/947) was created to include React Flow Types in globals by default.

Comment: `SyntheticInputEvent` actually seems to be a core type bundled with Flowtype as part of the react-dom integration. Does this require some additional configuration inside Sonar?

Comment: Globals can be set with property `sonar.javascript.globals` . However I created https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/issues/947 to fix this in SonarJS